# How to do an initial fade in into a game on game app start?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, fadein

I have a problem to understand why my initial black fade-in animation glitches on the first frame. In unity editor, on game start, my fade-in animation plays perfectly but after android build, when I start my game, the fade-in into the first scene (the main menu) doesn't work. On the first frame there is a flash of the whole scene and after that the fade-in plays partialy and the game continues. No error messages, no other problems with the game.

The interesting part is that I created a fade-out animation for my exit button and it is working perfectly.

I tried tutorials on scene transitions, fade in fade out between scenes but those tutorials won't help. They do transitions from already existing scenes.

Here is the link of the tutorial which helped me partially:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oadq-IrOazg

The Scene Manager

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class GManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    public GameObject options;
    public GameObject pause;
    public GameObject levelChanger;
    public bool hide;
    public bool show;

    public void UIDefaults()
    {
        hide = true;
        show = false;
    }

    //Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;                   //Set the target frame rate to 60fps
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 1;                     // Sync framerate to monitors refresh rate


        levelChanger.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
        menu.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
        options.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
        pause.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("OnStart");
    }

    IEnumerator OnStart()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.15f);
        levelChanger.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The UI Manager - exit button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    public GameObject levelChanger;
    public Animator animatorLevelChanger;
    public Animator animatorMain;
    public bool hide;
    public bool show;

    public void UIDefaults()
        {
            hide = true;
            show = false;
        }
    /* --- EXIT APPLICATION --- */
    public void Exit()
        {
        UIDefaults();
        animatorMain.SetBool("MainBool", hide);
        StartCoroutine("OnExit");
        }

    IEnumerator OnExit()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.15f); // wait for animation to end.
        menu.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
        levelChanger.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
        animatorLevelChanger.SetTrigger("LevelFadeOut");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); 
        Application.Quit();
    }
    /* --- EXIT APPLICATION --- */
}
```

Simply I need help or a link for a tutorial which can show me how I can create a fade-in into my first scene (main menu) when I start the app on android.

Comment: Are the `Application.targetFrameRate` or `QualitySettings.vSyncCount` going to be correct in Android at 60 and 1, respectively? Are you running your build on an Android emulator or on a physical phone?

Comment: @Eliasar  I'm running my build on an android device with Android 5.2. I think that the frame rate is good but I'm thinking about the removal of the vSync line. I dont have a preloader so that is maybe a problem. I think that I'm trying to load to much stuff on the first frame so my next move will be to create a preloader scene, async load the scene in the background with the fade-in and we'll see... ;)